# Python - Take screenshot including mouse cursor

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, screenshot

I am currently trying to take a screenshot who include mouse cursor using `PIL.ImageGrab`.

This is my code:

```py
import ctypes, win32gui, win32ui
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab

size = round(ctypes.windll.shcore.GetScaleFactorForDevice(0) / 100 * 32)

cursor = get_cursor()

pixdata = cursor.load()
minsize = [size, None]

width, height = cursor.size
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):

        if pixdata[x, y] == (0, 0, 0, 255):
            pixdata[x, y] = (0, 0, 0, 0)

        else:
            if minsize[1] == None:
                minsize[1] = y

            if x < minsize[0]:
                minsize[0] = x

ratio = ctypes.windll.shcore.GetScaleFactorForDevice(0) / 100

img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=None, include_layered_windows=True)

pos_win = win32gui.GetCursorPos()
pos = (round(pos_win[0]*ratio), round(pos_win[1]*ratio))


img.paste(cursor, pos, cursor)

img.save("screenshot.png")
```

And this is my `get_cursor()` function:

```py
def get_cursor():

    hcursor = win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[1]
    hdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(win32gui.GetDC(0))
    hbmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    hbmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 36, 36)
    hdc = hdc.CreateCompatibleDC()
    hdc.SelectObject(hbmp)
    hdc.DrawIcon((0,0), hcursor)
    
    bmpinfo = hbmp.GetInfo()
    bmpbytes = hbmp.GetBitmapBits()
    bmpstr = hbmp.GetBitmapBits(True)
    cursor = Image.frombuffer('RGB', (bmpinfo['bmWidth'], bmpinfo['bmHeight']), bmpstr, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1).convert("RGBA")
    
    win32gui.DestroyIcon(hcursor)    
    win32gui.DeleteObject(hbmp.GetHandle())
    hdc.DeleteDC()


    pixdata = cursor.load()
    minsize = [32, None]

    width, height = cursor.size
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):

            if pixdata[x, y] == (0, 0, 0, 255):
                pixdata[x, y] = (0, 0, 0, 0)

            else:
                if minsize[1] == None:
                    minsize[1] = y

                if x < minsize[0]:
                    minsize[0] = x


    return cursor
```

The problem is that some cursors are not pasted at the right position because they have pixels to the left of their position like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J89vl.png) (do not pay attention to the quality).

How can I place the cursor image correctly (or otherwise solve the problem)?

Comment: Add a delay before the image grab so that you can position the cursor in the correct place.  This is similar to the  delay feature in the windows snipping tool

Comment: @cup The problem is not the actual position of the cursor but how the image returned by my `get_cursor` function is placed. On both screenshots, the real cursor is exactly at the same position (and is not moving)

Comment: https://github.com/BoboTiG/python-mss/issues/55#issuecomment-580481146 there is a part of code you want

Comment: @Kal-1 I tried this solution but I can't save or display this image format

Comment: "The problem is not the actual position of the cursor but how the image returned by my get_cursor function is placed." Yes; cursors have a "hot spot" which indicates where the OS will position the cursor image relative to the actual mouse position. It's effectively hard-coded data that depends on the image. It might be represented in the `win32gui.GetCursorInfo()` result somewhere; try reading the documentation. In the worst case, you can just hard-code the offset yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mouse cursors have a "hot spot" which is the position where the image is placed relative to the cursor position
This "hot spot" can be obtained like this:

```py
import win32gui

hcursor = win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[1]
hotspot = win32gui.GetIconInfo(hcursor)[1:3]
```

So the full code is:

```py
import ctypes, win32gui, win32ui
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab


def get_cursor():
    hcursor = win32gui.GetCursorInfo()[1]
    hdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(win32gui.GetDC(0))
    hbmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    hbmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 36, 36)
    hdc = hdc.CreateCompatibleDC()
    hdc.SelectObject(hbmp)
    hdc.DrawIcon((0,0), hcursor)
    
    bmpinfo = hbmp.GetInfo()
    bmpstr = hbmp.GetBitmapBits(True)
    cursor = Image.frombuffer('RGB', (bmpinfo['bmWidth'], bmpinfo['bmHeight']), bmpstr, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1).convert("RGBA")
    
    win32gui.DestroyIcon(hcursor)    
    win32gui.DeleteObject(hbmp.GetHandle())
    hdc.DeleteDC()


    pixdata = cursor.load()


    width, height = cursor.size
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):

            if pixdata[x, y] == (0, 0, 0, 255):
                pixdata[x, y] = (0, 0, 0, 0)


    hotspot = win32gui.GetIconInfo(hcursor)[1:3]

    return (cursor, hotspot)

cursor, (hotspotx, hotspoty) = get_cursor()
cursor.save("cursor.png")


ratio = ctypes.windll.shcore.GetScaleFactorForDevice(0) / 100

img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=None, include_layered_windows=True)

pos_win = win32gui.GetCursorPos()
pos = (round(pos_win[0]*ratio - hotspotx), round(pos_win[1]*ratio - hotspoty))


img.paste(cursor, pos, cursor)

img.save("screenshot.png")
```